# Convolving a vector with itself n times using Scipy without for loops

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

I want to convolve a vector with itself n times without using a for loop (I'm new to numpy).
Right now I have this:

```
def build_gaussian_filter(filter_size):
    ones_array = np.array([1, 1])
    result = np.array([1, 1])
    for i in range(filter_size-2):
        result = np.convolve(ones_array, result)
    return result
```

Is there a numpy way to do this without loops?
Thanks

Comment: There may be. But I would be surprised if it were necessary — are you doing so many convolutions that it's a significant time sink?

Comment: If so, I think there's probably a way to represent multiple convolutions as a matrix power operation under a Fourier transform...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in window functions:

```
scipy.signal.windows.gaussian(5,1) * 6
>>> array([0.8120117 , 3.63918396, 6.        , 3.63918396, 0.8120117 ])
```

Gives almost the same result a your function:

```
build_gaussian_filter(5)
>>> [1 4 6 4 1]
```

Although that seems to be a fluke, as with increasing window sizes your results diverge from the kernel returned by scipy. You could look at the generalized gaussian window in scipy as well.

Comment: Ah, I see, is this the motivation behind doing multiple convolutions? If so, this is a good answer. Would be nice for clarification from the OP though.